# Set Range returning wrong address

Tags: excel, vba

The code is setting a range based on the location of the active cell. This range is to be used in part to create a pie chart.

```
Item.Address is $Z$6
ActiveCell.Address is $Z$5
Item.Offset(1, 0).Address is $Z$7
Item.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0).Address is $Z$13
```

I am expecting the code below to return the address $Z$7:$Z$13

```
Set DataRange = ActiveCell.Range(Item.Offset(1, 0), Item.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0))
```

However it returns the address of $AY$11:$AY$17

Similar logic prior to this call works

```
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(2, -1), ActiveCell.Offset(2, -1).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)).Address is $Y$7:$Y$13
```

Comment: ActiveCell v ActiveSheet... Issue when you have been writing code for 15 hours!

Answer (score 0):

typo - ActiveCell.Range should be Activesheet.Range